# some errors about jasmine clock in Angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Here are codes:

```
// component
   export class MockDateComponent implements OnInit {
     date: number;
     // ...
     initDate() {
       this.date = new Date().getTime()
     }
   } 

// spec
describe('...', () => {
  // ...
  it('should init date with current timestamp', () => {
    jasmine.clock().mockDate(new Date(1546263001000));
    component.initDate();
    expect(component.date).toBe(1546263001000);
  });
})
```

Codes above will pass.
But whilte I add code below to `spec`file, it throw errors `Error: Jasmine Clock was unable to install over custom global timer functions. Is the clock already installed?` and I don't know why.

```
describe('...', () => {
  // ...
  beforeEach(() => {
    // ...
    jasmine.clock().install();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
  });
  it('should init date with current timestamp', () => {
    // codes inner are the same
  });
})
```

The project was created by Angular Cli, here are version info:

```
@angular/common v6.1.10`
Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Node: 11.1.0
OS: darwin x64
```

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600819/conflict-between-zone-js-and-jasmines-clock It says to uninstall first in `beforeEach` and then do install/uninstall

Comment: I've tried that, it solve the error I mentioned above, but uninstall before install looks quite strange. What's more, the solution of your link throw new Error  `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Comment: I do not use timeout or interval in codes, but it seems that this is an error related to them. Jasmine really makes me confused